# Join two tables using pyspark hive context

Tags: pyspark, hivecontext

I am seeing below error when joining two hive tables using pyspark hive context .

error:

> """)   File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py",
>   line 552, in sql   File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in **call**   File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 36, in deco   File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 300, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o41.sql. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   cancelled because SparkContext was shut down EX:

```
lsf.registerTempTable('temp_table')

    out = hc.sql(
            """INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE AAAAAA   PARTITION (day ='2017-09-20')
               SELECT tt.*,ht.id
                FROM temp_table tt
                 JOIN hive_table ht
             ON tt.id = ht.id
        """)
```

Also how to parameterize day ?

Comment: Perhaps a memory issue. You need to look at your detailed logs